# Text Cut from left edge when gravity is set to right

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a simple form layout with label and edit text in front of each other(Horizontal Linear layout with weight 1 each). I have to make edit text aligned at right. When text exceeds in the textview it is cropped at the left edge of the view which is obvious.

I want text to be cropped from right instead of left by still having the gravity to right. iOS scroll the text to first character but android does not!

```
What I have tried till now :
1. Putting it in scrollview : Align right not work in this case
```

Is there any way to force textview to make text visible from the beginning by still having gravity right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:ellipsize** attribute.
From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)

> If set, causes words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle.

Comment: Ellipsize is not working I dont know why. I have tried both programatically and in xml